# How to make .click animations to work in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to make a small quiz and can't get the submit button to make the .activequestion class fade out and switch to the next question down the line. I'm wondering if my .next() isn't working in this scenario? I was under the impression that as long as the elements were siblings this operator could be used. Here's the jQuery code:

```
var main = function() {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var currentquestion = $('.activequestion')
        var nextquestion = currentquestion.next();
        currentquestion.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('activequestion')

        if (currentquestion.id == 'question5') {
            $('#scorepage').addClass('activequestion');
        }

        nextquestion.fadeIn(1000).addClass('activequestion');

    })


    $('#restart').click(function () {
        var currentquestion = $('.activequestion');
        currentquestion.fadeOut(1000).removeClass('activequestion');
        $('#question1').addClass('activequestion');

    })

}

$document.ready(main)
```

The restart button also isn't working the way it should.

Thanks for the help! Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zach94/6u02a54q/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issues is that `$document.ready(main)` should read `$(document).ready(main)`.

Also, on jsfiddle, you will want to remove links to your external css and js files, and also make sure that jQuery is actually loaded.

Here is a working fiddle from yours: http://jsfiddle.net/6u02a54q/1/

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful

Comment: You need the bit that shows question1 in your current code (`$('#question1').addClass('activequestion');`) to have a `.fadeIn(1000)`. Otherwise the class `display` property is overriden by an element style of `display:none` from the div being faded out earlier.